# How to set up a handshake with BizTalk 2013 R2

Tags: biztalk, handshake, biztalk-2013r2

For a proof of concept I'm working on, I need to implement handshaking.
As I am pretty new with this kind of validation, I don't really know how to start.

Do I need to develop a custom behavior or there is an adapter which make the job?

The purpose of that PoC is to connect to a JSON API in order to receive event data from Event Grid.

I will be using BizTalk 2013 R2 to process received data.

If you guys need more information don't hesitate I will update my posts.

---

EDIT 27/05:

The purpose of this PoC is to receive events from Event Grid. To use it I need to implement three part (according to dev team): Handshake, Receiving event data and Validation by using JWT token.

For handshaking, I will receive a "request" in JSON with a validationCode and an eventType which had to be "Microsoft.EventGrid.SubscriptionValidationEvent" type and I had to return a response with the validationCode and a HTTP response with 200 result.

If handshaking fail, the flow has to stop.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by handshaking?  Is it an authentication token you need to get?  Do you need to port knock?    Yes, you would probably need to develop a custom behavior if it isn't something that a BizTalk adapater does out of the box.

Comment: your scenario is not clear, y'll connect to an API or listen to an Event grid? what's expected if the handshake faile?

Comment: @Hichamveo I updated my original post

Comment: For the receive part of the handshaking you just need a WCF-WebHttp two-way receive location with a JSON Decoder.   Are you just returning the same validationCode?  What format is the response in?  JSON again?   Still not enough details of the rest of the flow.  What in particular are you having a problem with?

Comment: And really, if they want to do stuff with Event Grid in Azure, you should be using BIzTalk 2016 with FP3 or BIzTalk 2020 and then you can use the new adapters that are designed for Azure resources.

Comment: Thank you for you response about handshake and yes I will return the same validationCode in JSON too so a two-way RL and JSON Decoder/Encoder should do the trick. My second problem is for the JWT token part. I assume I will have to develop a custom behavior to handle it? I only have BizTalk 2013 R2 for this customer so do you know if I can handle EventGrid with a Custom Component/Behavior ?

Comment: Yes, a custom behaviour to get the JWT token would be the way to go.  I've done it for various flavors of OAuth.   I've not played with EventGrid.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Do you know if there is a way to consume REST service throught WebHttp adapter with https URI ? In order to get the authentication token (handshake) I have an https URI (https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token). I know it's out of the box with BizTalk 2016 but I only have BizTalk 2013 R2. Maybe a custom adapter?

Comment: As previously said, a Custom Behavior, rather than a custom adapter, would do the job.

Comment: I was wondering where the token is stored? Because JWT token has a time limit. So if I receive several request I don't have to get a new token for each request. Can you enlighten me, please?